# Almacenar un div en una variable en jquery y no estoy lograndolo

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dataset, atributos

Hola muy buenas a todos

Estoy intentando colocar este codigo ,

```
document.getElementById('paso-' + element.dataset.paso)
```

que naturalmente me trae un div que posee el id que comienza con paso-, y que posee el dataset.paso que requiero (1,2,3, etc), pero al querer utilizarlo en jquery no estoy logrando dar con la solucion, he intentado:

```
$('#paso').data("paso"),
```

pero solo me devuelve el numero de paso y no el elemento del dom como lo hacia la funcion de js vanilla

Aclaro que el fin de esto, es animar unos div, que son multi pasos de un formulario

mi HTML

```
 <fieldset class="paso active" id="paso-1">
              <h3>Solicitud Crediticia</h3>
              <p>
                  Bienvenido a nuestro simulador de prestamos! Si te interesa obtener
                  uno, llena el siguiente formulario y descubri que oferta tenemos para vos.
              </p>
              <button id="siguiente1" data-paso="1" data-al_paso="2" class="siguienteButton" type="button">Siguiente</button>
            </fieldset>
        
            <fieldset class="paso" id="paso-2">
              <h3>Ingresa tus datos</h3>
              <div class="contenedorInputs">
                <input id="nombre" class="" type="text" name="nombre" required placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                <input id="apellido" class="" type="text" name="apellido" required placeholder="Apellido">
                <input id="mail" class="" type="email" name="mail" required placeholder="Email" >
              </div>
              <button id="anterior0" data-paso="2" data-al_paso="1"  class="anteriorButton" type="button">Anterior</button>
              <button id="siguiente2" data-paso="2" data-al_paso="3" class="siguienteButton" type="button">Siguiente</button>
            </fieldset>
```

y mi JS codigo al momento es, la idea es concatenar todo en esta funcion y hacer cambie el fieldset al hacer click y actualizar unas barras de progreso

```
 ("#formSimulador").on("click", function(e){
  let boton = e.target;
  let botonAtras = $(boton).hasClass("siguienteButton")
  let botonAdelante = $(boton).hasClass("anteriorButton")
  if (botonAtras || botonAdelante){
    let pasoActual = document.getElementById('paso-' + boton.dataset.paso);
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr con `.data()`? Esa es una función de jQuery que no tiene relación con `element.dataset`. Nos ayudaría que añadas más código para tener una mejor idea de lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: @Mateo habia entendido que data tenia la misma funcion que dataset. entonces estoy mas perdido aun

Comment: Disculpa por confundirte. Al parecer `.data()` tiene la capacidad de leer la propiedad `dataset` del elemento pero al modificarla no tiene efecto sobre el código HTML, sino que se guarda como una propiedad más del elemento en javascript.

Comment: @mateo una consulta mas, al querer hacer el submit al realizar una llamada ajax con metodo post, no reinicia el formulario, osea estoy buscando enviar el formulario y limpiar el mismo volverlo a 0, pero no lo estoy logrando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, `getElementById()` recibe una cadena de texto que contiene el id del elemento.

```
document.getElementById('paso-' + element.dataset.paso)
```

La función `$()` recibe una cadena de texto con un selector css. El código equivalente sería:

```
$('#paso-' + element.dataset.paso)
```

o

```
$('#paso-' + $(element).data("paso"))
```

El número de paso lo tienes en el botón, mientras que el id "paso-" lo tienen tus `fieldset`. Con `$('#paso').data("paso")` estás intentando acceder a un dato de `fieldset` que además no posee.

Comment: Si!! tarde en responder, logre encontrar justamente esa respuesta, la correcta es la primera opcion